# TCP/IP Message Framing Examples

Tags: c++, tcp

I'm trying to find concrete examples of how to manage breaking an incoming stream of data on a TCP/IP socket and aggregating this data in a buffer of some sort so that I could find the messages in it (variable length with header + delimiters) and extract them to reconstruct the messages for the receiving application.

Any good pointers/links/examples on an efficient way of doing this would be appreciated as I couldn't find good examples online and I'm sure this problem has been addressed by others in an efficient way in the past.

- Efficient memory allocation of aggregation buffer
- Quickly finding the message boundaries of a message to extract it from the buffer

Thanks

David

Answer (score 3):

I've found that the simple method works pretty well.

- Allocate a buffer of fixed size double the size of your biggest message. One buffer. Keep a pointer to the end of the data in the buffer.
- Allocation happens once. The next part is the message loop:
- If not using blocking sockets, then `poll` or `select` here.
- Read data into the buffer at the end-data pointer. Only read what will fit into the buffer.
- Scan the new data for your delimiters with `strchr`. If you found a message:

  - `memcpy` the message into its own buffer. (Note: I do this because I was using threading and you probably should too.)
  - `memmove` the remaining buffer data to the beginning of the buffer and update the end of data pointer.
  - Call the processing function for the message. (Send it to the thread pool.)

There are more complicated methods. I haven't found them worth the bother in the end but you might depending on circumstances.

You could use a circular buffer with beginning and end of data pointers. Lots of hassle keeping track and computing remaining space, etc.

You could allocate a new buffer after finding each message. You wouldn't have to copy so much data around. You do still have to move the excess data into a new message buffer after finding the delimiter.

Do **not** think that dumb tricks like reading one byte at a time out of the socket will improve performance. Every system call round-trip makes an 8 kB `memmove` look cheap.